# How to correctly setup Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed from mini.iso to use NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, network-manager, netplan

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from [mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso) using Ethernet/cable.

Then I have installed MATE desktop to it by `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^`.

But the Network Manager tray icon/*nm-applet* says that *Ehernet Network* — *device not managed*:

What is the simplest method to setup the system to use NetworkManager back?

---

Note: please do not close this as duplicate - I need complete reproducible solution in one place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To transform the system to normal MATE one should:

Remove *systemd-networkd* renderer:

```
sudo rm -v /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
sudo rm -v /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

Restore Network Manager renderer:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
EOF
```

Apply netplan configuration with:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Restart NetworkManager

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

Optionally restore contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
EOF
```

---

Note: this method is also applicable to Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS, 21.04 and 21.10.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited the great answer to get all pieces into it. For now it is really reproducible. I appreciate the first clue about */etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml*. Manually compared the contents of */etc* folders and discovered the same.

Comment: Please do not recommend disabling the networkd service. This is not necessary, and diverges from the normal state of an installed system.

Comment: @slangasek thanks for the edit. For now I know more about netplan than before :)

Comment: This works very well indeed, thanks for the edit.

Comment: @N0rbert, can this also be applied on systems created from the Ubuntu Live Server iso files?

Comment: @sudodus I'm not sure. If you have time please try on VM.

Comment: @N0rbert, It works with a minor fix :-) See this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367302/how-to-make-a-portable-ubuntu-server/1367303#1367303

Comment: @sudodus, great. Bookmarked.