# How to make a portable Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, usb, portable

It can be useful to have an Ubuntu Server in an SSD connected via USB or in a fast USB pendrive and run it in different computers. The wired network system of Ubuntu Desktop and the community flavours works [without tweaks] in different computers, but the Ubuntu Server seems dedicated to the computer, where it was installed.

How can I make [at least the wired] network system of Ubuntu Server portable between computers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Portable Ubuntu Server

**Edit May 2023:**

#### Use Ubuntu's own compressed image file

Ubuntu creates daily images for testing purposes. You can use these compressed image files with Ubuntu Server, because when extracted and cloned they are portable out of the box:

- can be booted both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode and
- works where the built-in linux drivers can manage the hardware

I would recommend that you use an image of a released LTS version (in May 2023: [**jammy** preinstalled server image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/jammy/daily-preinstalled/current/))

You find [more details here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692).

**End of Edit May 2023**

#### Network

I applied the [method by N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257467/how-to-correctly-setup-ubuntu-18-04-lts-installed-from-mini-iso-to-use-networkma/1257474#comment2347862_1257474) to Ubuntu Server installed from the file

```
ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso
```

The following method makes the installed server's network portable between computers. I installed it in a [Toshiba laptop](http://www.toshiba.se/laptops/satellite-pro/c850/satellite-pro-c850-19w/) and tested it in a Dell Latitude E7240 and a Lenovo V130.

The main difference compared to the method by N0rbert is that the package `network-manager` must be installed (*before* tampering with the network system).

```
sudo apt install network-manager
```

Restore Network Manager renderer:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
EOF
```

Apply netplan configuration with:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Restart NetworkManager

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

I ran also the following command to restore contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` (without checking if it was necessary)

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
EOF
```

#### More details in order to make the installation portable

- It is a good idea to unplug, disconnect or otherwise disable the internal drive when the Ubuntu Server is installed. Otherwise it can easily happen that part of the boot system will be written to the internal drive, and the system will not be portable. (It is very easy to unplug the internal drive of the Toshiba where I installed the system.)
- I installed the system in UEFI mode, and in order to make it portable also to computers running in BIOS mode alias CSM alias legacy mode, booting via grub-pc must also be implemented.
- See the detailed tips in the following links,

  - [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step)
  - [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)
  - [Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS)

## Custom Portable Ubuntu system

This method can also be used to create a custom portable Ubuntu system, not only a server, but also a custom desktop system for example with a simple window manager (like `fluxbox`).

Comment: I can't wait to give this a try.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron, and I can't wait for your result :-P Maybe it needs polishing.