# transferred ubuntu server HDD to another machine- now ubuntu doesn't see the network card

Tags: server, steam

So I have absolutely no idea how command line operating systems work, my knowledge is very basic.
By way of background, I'm running an ubuntu server on a machine which hosts a game server running on Steam

The machine has been giving me trouble, and the game server crashes frequently, I've been told its most likely a memory problem but it would be difficult to debug.

Because I have no idea how to install ubuntu server (it was installed as a favour by an IT guy years ago) I thought in my infinite wisdom I could just put the drive in another computer.

It worked, sort of, except that ubuntu doesn't see the network card. I tried to google possible solutions but everything starts with the command "sudo" and ubuntu gives me another error
"steam is not in the sudoers file" and so now I'm sort of stuck as this just leads to an even deeper rabbit hole
is there a quickfix that I am missing?

Comment: That can be fixed according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367302/how-to-make-a-portable-ubuntu-server) to another question at AskUbuntu. This is easy, when the server is still in its original computer, but complicated, in a new one (because the network does not work, when you want to download `network-manager`). And you do need `sudo` (to run some commands with elevated permissions).

Comment: See this link: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password/24024#24024). You must know which user that has sudo permissions. Check with `grep '^sudo:' /etc/group`