# Ubuntu Desktop or Server ISO on USB key

Tags: server, usb, desktop-environments, iso

I intend to create a bootable USB key that would launch a Windows application, running under Wine, on an Ubuntu distribution. The Windows application will be started automatically after system load and will takeover the user interface. For short, this USB construction is just to launch this application and the implementation is mostly playing with the automatic execution of scripts.
As the only interface I need for working with the above is the terminal, I would like to know which image I have to use: the Desktop or the Server, knowing that I shall configure a minimum resources server (if proposed).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you write in the question, you can start from both a desktop iso file and a server iso file.

- I think it would be **easier** to make it work from a **desktop** iso file, because it is easier to make a portable system that way, for example as a **persistent live** system made by [mkusb-dus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).
- If it is important to make a **light-weight** system, you should start from a **server** iso file. The server must be [installed into the USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step), and if you want a [portable network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367302/how-to-make-a-portable-ubuntu-server), it must be fixed.

Comment: Thank you, very useful answer, I think I'll test both cases for the simple reason of the Wine behavior (Posix calls possible issues). There is one question though: why would I consider the portable network since my use case is in fact just a local machine one (a.k.a.... "desktop" :-) ) ?

Comment: @GingerOpariti, You are welcome. If you don't want or need a portable network, don't bother with it :-)

Comment: @GingerOpariti, If you think that you might need a network in the future, when connected to another computer, for example in order to install or upgrade some program, it is worthwhile to make it portable now, that you still have [access to] the computer, where you install and tweak the installed server system. (Desktop systems will get portable internet by default, at least wired internet (ethernet) is very portable.)