# Install Ubuntu with vanilla MATE desktop (no Software Boutique or Welcome snaps)

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate

As I don't want unconfined snaps in my system, I would like to know what is the best way to have a Mate desktop on Ubuntu without installing the unconfined snaps that are included with Ubuntu MATE installation. i.e.: install Ubuntu Server and then install mate desktop package.

To clarify, I only want the standard Mate desktop without snaps.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just download Ubuntu server and install the `mate-desktop-environment` package?

Comment: Yep, that's the only option I know. Do you know if there is some problem using Ubuntu Server as a desktop? (like a different kernel configuration unsuitable for gaming or unnecessary services installed by default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You install Ubuntu MATE task on the 20.04 LTS minimal system obtained from [netboot mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso) by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

and it will not have Snaps preinstalled. Please note that you need to fix Network Manager by following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1257474/66509).

If you have installed Snaps by yourself - remove both by:

```
sudo snap remove software-boutique --purge
sudo snap remove ubuntu-mate-welcome --purge
```

---

Or more debian-like way by installing binaries which were compiled from the same [`mate-desktop-environment` source package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/mate-desktop-environment):

```
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment mate-desktop-environment-extra
```

Comment: Thank you! I like the debian-like method as I want something similar to a debian install with Mate desktop.

Comment: Just in case, will this method work using Ubuntu Server media or is there some problem like a different kernel configuration unsuitable for gaming?

Comment: It should work for Ubuntu Server media. But I prefer mini.iso.

Comment: Ok, thank you! :)