# Wifi tray says "Device not ready" in Ubuntu MATE for Raspberry Pi 400

Tags: networking, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate, 21.10

### Setup

I have installed [Ubuntu Server 21.10](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) on `Raspberry Pi 400`, configured it as described [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview) and to get desktop environment I have installed `Ubuntu MATE` by running `sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop`.
I have installed and configured `tightvncserver` to remote access the machine.

I am able to `ssh` and `vnc` to the machine.

### Issue

I am not able to manage `wifi` from the taskbar also taskbar looks incomplete.
[Screenshot of the desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq8Ic.jpg).

I have tried few online suggestions like restarting `NetworkManager` or removing unused packages, but nothing helped.

Not sure if I need to install any missing package, appreciate any help.

**PS**:
I have to go via this route i.e. first configure `Ubuntu Server` then install desktop environment because I want to do it `headless` without any external monitor.

Comment: You chose difficult path. Ubuntu MATE 21.10 is available from official site: 64-bit - https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/arm64/impish/ ; 32-bit - https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/armhf/impish/ . Fixing device-not ready maybe possible by following https://askubuntu.com/a/1257474/66509 .

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert, I can't directly use desktop environment because it require initial setup which require external monitor :(. I was trying the fix over `vnc` but now it doesn't connect to `WiFi`. I have no way to verify it now without external monitor.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the commands: `iwconfig` and: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and, finally: `ps aux | grep Network` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Sure @chili555, I currently don't have external monitor to check it. Will share it after connecting to external monitor.